# Extracting the numerical values of a xts object

Tags: r, xts

I want to extract the numerical values of a xts object. Let's look at an example

```
data <- new.env()
starting.date <- as.Date("2006-01-01")
nlookback <- 20
getSymbols("UBS", env = data, src = "yahoo", from = starting.date)
Reg.curve <- rollapply(Cl(data$UBS), nlookback, mean, align="right")
```

The `Reg.cuve` is still a xts object but actually I'm just interested in the running means. How can I modify `Reg.curve` to get a numerical vector?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `coredata`:

```
reg.curve.num <- coredata(Reg.curve)
# or, if you want a vector:
reg.curve.num <- drop(coredata(Reg.curve))
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `drop(coredata(Reg.curve))` over `as.numeric(Reg.curve)`?

Comment: @GSee: the former doesn't assume/coerce the result to numeric, so it's more general. It works whether `Reg.curve` is numeric, integer, logical, character, etc.

Comment: I wish there was a column that included the time indices.

Comment: @EngrStudent: the time indices are in the `index` attribute. You can access it with `index(Reg.curve)`. It can't be a column because xts/zoo objects are matrices and therefore can only contain one data type (i.e. they can't have a Date column and a numeric column).

Answer (score 1):

To extract the numerical values of any `xts`, `ts`, or `zoo` object use:

```
as.numeric(Reg.curve)
```