# Access different columns in xts object in R

Tags: r, charts, xts, quantmod

How Can I access individual columns in R?

My `xts` object is:

```
> glimpse(`prod`)
Observations: 2,341
Variables: 3
$ DL_prod     (dbl) 301.50, 303.75, 308.50, 311.00, 319.00, 318.25, 320.00, 320.75, 318.00, 319.00, 315.00, 313.50, 313.00,...
$ MWF_prod     (dbl) 301.500, 309.000, 311.250, 319.750, 354.563, 322.000, 324.000, 321.500, 320.065, 730.000, 316.160, 315....
$ MA_prod      (dbl) 301.500, 302.688, 304.946, 308.750, 316.500, 315.500, 318.500, 315.250, 313.000, 215.500, 311.500, 310....

> str(`prod`)
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-01/2016-01-08 containing:
  Data: num [1:2341, 1:6] 302 304 308 311 319 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "DL_prod" "MWF_prod" "MA_prod"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-01-11 17:26:06"
```

I wish to calculate Simple moving averages for `DL_prod` column.

But I can't select that column like:

```
prod$DL_prod
```

I want to calculate SMA by something like:

```
SMA(prod$DL_prod)
```

This will also help me using the `quantmod` package for `timeseries` analysis.
For example I would like to use the `chartSeries(prod)` method to plot DL_prod column.
Looked everywhere but can't seem to find any info on this. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881475/extracting-the-numerical-values-of-a-xts-object

Comment: You say you can't select a column via `prod$DL_prod`. You should be able to, so you need to tell us what "doesn't work" means. Is there an error, warning, does it return incorrect data, etc? Please also add the output from `sessionInfo` to your question.

Comment: `> `prod`$DL_prod
Error: object 'DL_prod' not found`

Comment: `> prod$DL_prod
Error: object 'prod' not found`

Comment: Please also add the output from `sessionInfo` to your question.